# How to upload JSON data to Azure storage blob using Azure Blob storage bindings for Azure Functions in Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I want to upload JSON data as a .json file to Azure storage blobs using Azure Functions in Python.

Because I am using Azure Functions and not an actual server, I do not want to (and probably cannot) create a temporary file in local memory and upload that file to Azure blob storage using the Azure Blob storage client library v2.1 for Python ([reference link here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python-legacy#learn-about-the-sample-code)). Therefore, I want to use output blob storage bindings for Azure Functions ([reference link here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob?tabs=python#output)).

I am testing this out in an Azure Functions with an HTTP Trigger. I take in an Azure blob through an input blob storage binding (which is working just fine), process it, and update it by uploading a new Azure blob that overrides it (which is what I need help with). My function.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "inputblob",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "{containerName}/{blobName}.json",
      "connection": "MyStorageConnectionAppSetting",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "name": "outputblob",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "{containerName}/{blobName}.json",
      "connection": "MyStorageConnectionAppSetting",
      "direction": "out"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    }
  ]
}
```

And my Python code looks like this:

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import azure.storage.blob
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient
import json, os

def main(req: func.HttpRequest, inputblob: func.InputStream, outputblob: func.Out[func.InputStream]) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    # Initialize variable for tracking any changes
    anyChanges= False

    # Read JSON file
    jsonData= json.loads(inputblob.read())

    # Make changes to jsonData (omitted for simplicity) and update anyChanges

    # Upload new JSON file
    if anyChanges:
        outputblob.set(jsonData)

    return func.HttpResponse(f"Input data: {jsonData}. Any changes: {anyChanges}.")
```

However, this isn't working at all, with the following error being thrown ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vhw8D.png)):

> Value 'func.Out' is unsubscriptable

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

You want `bytes` or `str`, not `InputStream`, like this:

```py
def main(inputblob: func.InputStream, outputblob: func.Out[bytes], context: func.Context):
    ...
    # Write to output blob
    outputblob.set(jsonData)
```

`InputStream` [represents an *input* blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-functions/azure.functions.inputstream?view=azure-python).

See [this sample](https://github.com/yokawasa/azure-functions-python-samples/blob/master/v2functions/queue-trigger-blob-in-out-binding/__init__.py) for `str` and [this one](https://github.com/yokawasa/azure-functions-python-samples/blob/master/v2functions/blob-trigger-watermark-blob-out-binding/__init__.py) for `bytes`.

Later update:

The call to `json.loads()` returns a dictionary and for some reason `outputblob.set()` freaks out and needs some handholding, like this:

```py
def main(req: func.HttpRequest,
         inputblob: func.InputStream,
         outputblob: func.Out[bytes]) -> func.HttpResponse:

    jsonData = json.loads(inputblob.read())
    outputblob.set(str(jsonData))

    return func.HttpResponse(f"Input JSON: {jsonData}")
```

That should work (well it works on `func` version
`2.7.1948` at least).

Comment: Thank you! I see your point re: bytes vs InputStream, but it doesn't fix the "unsubscriptable" error: [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/rQayqV2.png)